# Connecting to a SQLite database from visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sqlite, database-connection

I did write some apps in the past that used access en sqlserver databases. These databases come with wizards however to help you create a connection to it.

Now, I want to add a new db connection in the Server explorer of visual studio 2008 to SQLite. I referenced the `System.Data.SQLite` assembly from [phxsoftware](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com). I am able to select the SQLite Database File (.NET Framework Data Provider for SQLite) as a Datasource. Then I tried to add as the connection string: `Data Source=g:\testsqlite.s3db; Version=3` (a database file I constructed using SQLite administrator).

When I hit the Test Connection button all seems to be fine, but when I hit OK, visual studio greets me with a message box that an unexpected error has occurred in the .Net Framework Dataprovider for Sqlite.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you just try "guessing" the connection string and writing some simple ADO.NET code to connect and do a simple query? In other words have you verified the designer is the issue and not System.Data.SQLite itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is discussed [here](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/t/329.aspx?PageIndex=2) Jaap34's answer solved the problem in my case. Actually when you see a screen that gives you only the option to enter a connection string you know you have run into an incompatibility issue. Uninstalling sqlite ADO provider, running devenv.exe /resetuserdata and reinstalling the ADO provider will give you a much more elaborate screen that gives you the possibility to browse to the database file.

Answer (score 0):

After your SQLite installation just restart your Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following for a soloution to reset the previous settings.

After looking back and forth over the internet, coming across a lot of different answers, I finally managed to get this working. This was my solution:

1. Close all open instances of Visual Studio.
2. Open the Command Prompt in an Administrator context by navigating to Start\All Programs\Accessories, right-clicking Command Prompt and choosing Run as Administrator.
3. Navigate to the install path of VS2008 - in my case (default on Vista x64) it was *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 9.0\Common7\IDE*
4. Run the command devenv /setup. It takes a little while, but be patient.
5. Start Visual Studio.

After following these steps, the setup is reset to default, so you'll have to reconfigure all startup options, fonts for the text editors etc. This could possibly be helped by running devenv /resetskippkgs instead, however it did not try that on my machine.